# C# WPF Run action when window has been created

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, progress-bar

I'm opening a new Window in a separate thread. I want the window to open and a job to run automatically, then report its progress to this window (i'll use a progress bar).

The action code that opens the window :

```
private void button_Run_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        ExecutorWindow myExecWindow = new ExecutorWindow();
        myExecWindow.Show();
}
```

The window code :

```
public partial class ExecutorWindow : Window
{
    BackgroundWorker execBackground = new BackgroundWorker();

    public ExecutorWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RunExecutor();
    }

    public void RunExecutor()
    {
        // CREATE BACKGROUNDWORKER FOR EXECUTOR
        execBackground.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(execBackground_DoWork);
        execBackground.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(execBackground_RunWorkerCompleted);
        execBackground.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        execBackground.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        // RUN BACKGROUNDWORKER
        execBackground.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void execBackground_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // CREATE EXECUTOR INSTANCE
        Executor myExecutor = new Executor(arg1, arg2);
        myExecutor.RunWhileRemainMachines();
    }

    private void execBackground_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("RunWorkerCompleted execBackground");
    }
}
```

But what happens is that the RunProcessingJob is called when I close the window only (which is normal because I run it after ShowDialog). I've tried to call it from the public ExecutorWindow() function but then it's the opposite : The window opens only when the RunProcessingJob is finished.

I dont know how to order that.. the behaviour I want is :
- click button
- open window
- run processing job (without further interaction from user)
- update window while running

Should I run my processing job in a BackgroundWorker called in public ExecutorWindow() ?

This processing job is already making use of BackgroundWorkers intensively and I'm not sure this is an elegant way to go..

EDIT : I've updated my code based on your comments (running directly my window without creating another thread. Plus i run my processing job from the window Constructor, but now in a separate thread to prevent the blocking issues I had).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on what `Executor.RunProcessingJob` does; the question can't be answered without looking at that code.

However, why are you creating the `ExecutorWindow` on another thread? If you want it to remain responsive to user input, you have no option other than to execute your processing on *yet another* thread (you mention `BackgroundWorker`, so this probably happens already). But if you do that, there's no need to create `ExecutorWindow` on its own thread in the first place.

Comment: Hi Jon, the RunProcessingJob is creating several BackgroundWorkers that perform some network operations (execution delay can vary from 60s to 5 mins). It's running X BackgroundWorkers at a time (X defined previously) and wait for a BackgroundWorker to finish before running another one. Once they all ran, it returns. Ideally I would like to update a progressbar in my ExecutorWindow each time one of these BackgroundWorkers finishes or report a progress.

Answer (score 0):

Override `ExecutorWindow`'s OnInitialize Method

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);
        RunExecutor();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start your processing thread in your ExecutorWindow class. Hook it to some event, Load, for example. Also I don't think you need a separate thread for creating & showing your ExecutorWindow. (If you don't want a modal dialog just call Show() instead of ShowDialog())